# HomeKit - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, homekit

I would like to create HMHome with HMHomeManager and addHomeWithName.

```
manager.addHomeWithName("Casa", completionHandler:
{
    (home:HMHome!, error:NSError!) in
    if error != nil {
        NSLog("Failed adding home, Error:\(error)")
    } else {
        NSLog("New Home \(home)")
    }
})
```

When the application is run I am getting the following error instead of creating Home

```
Failed adding home, Error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)"
(connection to service named com.apple.homed.xpc)
```

I read than this problem can be solved switching "HomeKit" to "On" at the "Capabilities" tab. But I don't have a developer ID that is enrolled in a Developer Program.

There is any way to use this functionality without pay 80€/year?? I only want to learn...
There is any way to enroll my Apple ID in free mode?

Thanks for all!!

Answer (score 5):

Turning on "Homekit" on the capabilities tab says it will do three things -

1. Add the Homekit entitlement to your app id
2. Add the Homekit entitlement to your entitlements file
3. Link the Homekit framework

You can't do 1 without the developer membership, but you can do 2 & 3 manually.

1. Select a folder in your project, such as "Supporting files" and select File->New->File (or Cmd-N)
2. Select "Resource" from the iOS section and then select "Property List" and click "Next"
3. Name the file "yourProject.entitlements" and click "Create"
4. Select the first line in newly created file ("Entitlements file") and click the + to add a new entry
5. Enter "com.apple.developer.homekit" with type "Boolean" and value "YES"
6. Select your Xcode project (Blue icon) at the top of the project navigator and go the "General" tab
7. At the bottom your will see "Linked Frameworks and Binaries".  Click "+" and add the Homekit.framework

Unfortunately this still gave me the same error you received, until I enabled Homekit in capabilities, so it seems you will need to get a paid developer membership to work with Homekit

Comment: Very help full you deserve +1 @Paulw11

Comment: I need your @Paulw11 help in Step 1, How can i add HomeKit entitlement to my app id ?Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: @Kamarshad Simply select the target in Xcode and then go to the 'Capabilities' tab.  Scroll down to 'HomeKit' and turn the switch on.

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely right, i missed that documentation thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello again and thanks for answering.

I answer myself. 
I managed to run my code running it from the Xcode 6 beta 3. 
In xcode 6 betas 1-3 you did not need any special capabilities To have to use homekit. This Beta 4 changed. You need to Have the homekit Both entitlement added to your entitlements file and your app ID.

To learn is perfect. and if I decide to take the step to the AppStore, I enroll in the Apple Developer Program.